# How can I improve this question?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

I recently asked a non-trivial [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165661/strange-python-error-on-windows-works-under-debugger).

It received two downvotes, but few comments on why the downvotes were applied. There were also two close votes, which were due to being off-topic for "why isn't this code working?"

I have tried to produce a minimal example, however it might not look like so due to the complex nature of the question, so I'm not sure what other rule I have broken here.

I don't really care about votes all that much, but I would like to phrase my questions better, so people are more likely going to answer them.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: In the comments below the question, information is captured that is not reflected in the question. That can be a reason for down-voting if the question is unclear. Personally, I am not a fan of debugging questions that cannot be reduced to a copy/paste example but require me to utilize a special setup or generate dummy inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advice in the comments below your question seems sound.  You didn't state where the exception occurred; that's one of the conditions for posting troubleshooting questions.

Without that information, readers of your question will have to comb through the code to find out where the error is, and most folks won't do this; they'll just downvote, vote to close, and move on.